# How to start off on a tab built in javascript/html instead of it being blank and having to click on one

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

Hello i have a tab system built in javascript/html and css currently it only displays anything if you click on it first but i was wondering if i could make tab content automatically show up when the page is loaded and the sidebar is opened here is the code that makes my sidebar work

```
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

[here](http://billischill.ddns.net) is the site i am currently working on if you want to see how the tabs behave

And here is my css

```
#tab-ul{
list-style-type: none;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #006666;
width: 100%:

}

/* Float the list items side by side */
#tab-li {
float: left;
background: #006666;
border-top: 1px solid #006666;

}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
a#tab-li a {
display: inline-block;
color: black;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom:12px;
padding-top:12px;
padding-left: 7px;
padding-right: 6px;
text-decoration: none;
transition: 0.3s;
font-size: 14px;
}

 /* Change background color of links on hover */
#tab-li a:hover {
background-color: #006666;

}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
#tab-li a:focus, .active {
background-color: darkcyan;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
display: none;


}
```

Comment: have you tried to set the tab class to active as default one?

Comment: Im sorry i dont understand

Comment: Have you tried adding the `active` class to the html tab you want open by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find this particular html

```
<div id="chatrooms" class="tabcontent">
```

change it to:

```
<div id="chatrooms" class="tabcontent" style="display: block;">
```

This should work for you. As I look in F12 tools I can't see class being changed on click, just the style property

For hightligh
locate:

```
<a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'chatrooms')">Chatrooms</a>
```

Change to:

```
<a href="#" class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, 'chatrooms')">Chatrooms</a>
```

Note that active class should follow after "tablinks" class because your javascript is replacing " active" including whitespace

Comment: Thanks that helped a bunch do you think you could tell me how to make the tab highlighted when it loads

Comment: <a href="#" class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, 'chatrooms')">Chatrooms</a>

I didn't really dig in code for first time, active class is actually set for tabs not for the tab-content

Just add class "active" to tab you want to highlight

Comment: That didn't seem to work it doesn't highlight it but when i click on the other tab it adds the content of that to the bottom of the current content but your first method worked great just didn't highlight the tab

Comment: @NicholasHendricks see updated answer and let me know if that helps

Comment: Thank you so much that helps so much